# Phantom js ignoring images during screen capture as PDF

Tags: phantomjs

I am using rasterize.js to generate a PDF document out of a local html file, containing text and images. The text appears just fine, but the images are ignored in the final PDF. I am including images as html img tags. e.g.

```
<img src="signature.png" alt="Sign" border="0" >
```

Comment: please show us more things because rasterize on local html files works perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

Try increasing the timeout. Default from the examples is only 200ms so see what happens when this is 2 seconds, e.g.

```
window.setTimeout(function () {
    page.render(output);
    phantom.exit();
}, 2000);
```